# Why is my background image not displaying properly in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, background-image, css-sprites

<del>Screenshot of the issue: here</del>

Webpage in Question: http://cure.org

Offending browser: Internet Explorer 7

You'll notice from the screenshot, or if you view this site in IE7, that the background image is not displaying for the content div (#modal-inner-content). Strangely, the image displays in the other divs where it is used (since it's a sprite, I'm using that same image for #modal-top-border and #modal-btm-border).

In all other browsers it displays properly, and even in IE8. I cannot seem to find what CSS rule (or lack thereof) I may be using that IE7 is choking on.

*NOTE: in order to get the modal screen, just click the link at the very top banner of the page that says "login to your CURE account*

Comment: Nevermind. Click the "login with facebook" at the top right

Comment: can you add how to get the box to pop up on the cure.org site. I couldn't find an action that prompted me to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with FutureKode. The background on #modal-inner-content isn't displaying because IE doesn't think the element hasLayout, which sometimes causes problems with other style declarations. To trigger hasLayout, the easiest way I see would be to style that div with width:576px (what Firebug is telling me the width of that div is). I'm assuming the width of that box never changes?

More on hasLayout, and what triggers it: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: Not totally sure this was the issue, but that would make sense. When I was initially trouble shooting this issue, I noticed our development code was not giving the issue, and the production was. But I couldn't see the discrepancy between the versions at a glance. But we just pushed an update and the issue is resolved. At a second glance I do see a width defined, so maybe it wasn't there before. Thx.

Comment: No prob! After my answer, I remembered that you had mentioned that it was working fine for you locally, which made me wonder what was up -- but not very long, because I just assume IE7's a jerk. :) (To note, I was using the IE Development Toolbar to check CSS properties (like you can in Firebug) and the width of #modal-inner-content hadn't been explicitly defined before.)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem in IE 7 with a transparent PNG acting as a background inside a `<div>`. Positioning the background at (0|0) fixed it for me:

```
background: url("images/bg-header.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it worked perfectly for why my image wasn't showing up in IE7.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, buttons with graphic backgrounds aren't displayed in IE7.

It seems that IE7 has problems with such HTML elements with borders, as setting `border-width:0` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just remembered that IE7 has a problem with mixed units in the background position property. so  -636px top should be  -636px 0

Comment: I'll have to test it - but the odd thing is that there is no problem with this on my local files, but only on the production. And I'm 99.99% certain there are no differences between the markup and css for this locally vs. production.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using some fix for IE and png images ?

If i remember correctly, most plugins/methods to enable transparency to background images by using the `filter` css property of IE made the background non-repeatable ..

It could be it ..

Comment: Good question...I'll have to check on that.

Comment: @JAG, try changing the rule to use a *`.gif`/`.jpg`* file and see if that changes things..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the image isn't showing up in IE7, but this could be a good intermediate fix. this should add a white background if the image doesn't show up.

Try changing #modal-inner-content from:

```
background: url(http://cure.org/img/modal-bg-xy.png?jcb=1284407379) repeat-y -636px 0%;
```

to:

```
background: url(http://cure.org/img/modal-bg-xy.png?jcb=1284407379) #fff repeat-y -636px 0%;
```

--- Edit - don't use above answer ---

Try wrapping the url in quotes:

```
background: url("http://cure.org/img/modal-bg-xy.png?jcb=1284407379") repeat-y -636px 0%;
```

Comment: The trouble then though it doesn't use transparency properly even when the image shows up, since the sprite makes use of shaded sides and transparent borders.

Comment: Ah. Well then. Don't try that. ;)

Comment: Plus that doesn't line up right with the top and bottom borders of the modal box.

Comment: Does ie7 do well with the lack of quotes? try wrapping the url in quotes.

Comment: @hookedonwinter none of my urls referenced have quotes though, so that would not make any sense - including the same exact image called in the #modal-top-border and #modal-btm border. (not saying it's out of IE's framework to "not make sense" - just sayin')

Answer (score 0):

I need to install ie7. My first try would be to add a width to #modal-inner-content

Comment: You can see the same behavior by using compatibility mode in IE8

Comment: Well the width shouldn't matter because there are elements inside with defined widths. Right?

Comment: when it comes to IE adding a width can fix haslayout issues

Answer (score 0):

Use the clear-rule:

```
clear:both;
```